# Is this some sort of autocomplete functionality? If so, how do I take advantage of it?

Tags: python, autocomplete, ide

I'm new to Python and just beginning to learn. I notice when I'm typing in either the IDE or the text editor, a box sometimes pops up that appears to allow for autofill / autocomplete. I'm not sure if that is what it is. If so, I would like to take advantage of it but I haven't figured out how to do so. I haven't found any explanations online although I may not be describing it enter image description here correctly. I have included a jpeg to show what I'm seeing.

Thanks.

[image: autocomplete box]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the picture it looks like it's telling you what argument you have to put inside.

Comment: You can use a code editor like Visual studio code to get autocomplete (i would recomend an extension that's called "Code runner". This lets you run the code by pressing Ctrl + Alt + N. You should also download the python extension)

Answer (score 0):

Boiski - I ran into it again (see pic). You are right. It is Python offering suggestions.

Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voIUl.jpg)